# create a file based on another file

Tags: awk

I have a text file that contains the following data. For example, aa.txt has some numbers. I need to extract the continuous numbers(minimum 3 numbers) from it.How can I do this with awk?

```
>aa.txt
31
35
36
37
38
39    
44
169
170
173
174
175
177
206 
>1a.txt
39
40
41
42
146
149
151
```

My desired output is shown below.

```
>aa.txt
35
36 
37
38
39
173
174
175
>1a.txt
 39
 40
 41
 42
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` and you example data:

```
awk 'f+1==$0 {a++} f+1!=$0 {if (a>1) {for (i=f-a;i<=f;i++) print i}a=0} {f=$0}' file
35
36
37
38
39
173
174
175
39
40
41
42
```

Some more readable:

```
awk '
f+1==$0 {
    a++} 
f+1!=$0 {
    if (a>1) {
        for (i=f-a;i<=f;i++)
            print i
        }a=0
    }
    {f=$0}
    ' file
```

How to print file name:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {print ">"FILENAME} f+1==$0 {a++} f+1!=$0 {if (a>1) {for (i=f-a;i<=f;i++) print i}a=0} {f=$0}' *
```

Change the `*` to match your file criteria.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.In the output, I need to print the file name from which it is extracted. Is it possible? Could you please explain the code?

Comment: @user3531678 Updated my post to include file name.  If you like it accept it :)

Comment: The updated code doesn't print like my desired output.

Comment: @user3531678 You should be able to change `File=` to  `>` like I have done on the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use v5.12;
use Text::Trim qw(trim);

my ($cur, $prev, $start); my $n=1; my $i=1;
while (<>) {
    trim $_;
    if ($.>1) { 
        $cur=$_;
        if ($cur==$prev+1) {
            $start=$prev if ($n==1);
            $n++;
        } else {
            if ($n>=3) {
                say "Range $i: $start-$prev";
                $i++;
            }
            $n=1;
        }
    }
    $prev=$cur;
}
```

Run it from the command line as `./test.pl file` where `file` is your sample file.

For sample input file:

```
31
35
36
37
38
39    
44
169
170
173
174
175
177
206 
39
40
41
42
146
149
151
```

The output is:

```
Range 1: 35-39
Range 2: 173-175
Range 3: 39-42
```